# How to get back border radius of a button:

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this HTML:

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email">
   <span class="input-group-btn input-space">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg inline input-space">Join</button>
   </span>
 </div>
```

where `input-space` is:

```
.input-group-btn.input-space {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Now, here's what I get:
[image]

Notice on the left, the button edges are not rounded? It seems to be some rule that Bootstrap applies to `input-group-btn`, because it expects there will be no space between the input and the button. How can I remove this, so the button has rounded edges on the left side, that are same like the ones already on the right side? I use Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to re-apply the border radius:

```css
.input-group-btn.input-space:last-child>.btn {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.input-group-btn.input-space {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email">
  <span class="input-group-btn input-space">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg inline input-space">Join</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how good an idea is to apply padding-left to the button. Maybe separate .border-radius into its own separate class?

Answer (score 1):

Currently bootstrap sets the border left and bottom radius to 0. You just need to override them.

```
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn {
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

This is what it looks like when I add the above code to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/kjvhqqz5/

[Image of fixed button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai7Fx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `input-group-btn` because you are going to have to shoehorn in your design.

```css
.input-group-btn.input-space {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg inline input-space">Join</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to get the button to be right next to the input box, so this isn't a feasible solution.

Comment: view in full screen view, the small rendering doesn't show it as it will be on a full page.

Comment: According to: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp, form-inline only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

Comment: I would go directly to bootstrap for documentation, but yes that sounds correct. What is your expected viewport width? (not mentioned in OP)